# Client side code for cricket live score updates

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, angular, ionic4

Can anyone please help me in my client side code : Iam developing an android application using ionic where iam working on live cricket score, i have purchased the cricket api.I have the idea how to connect to purchased cricket API using NODE Js, but when on client side iam using Angular 8 and iam hitting my server every 2s.Server is blocking my request after certain period of time.I just want to know the perfect way of doing the Angular 8 code so that my server will not block the request.I know about socket IO, but then, still i need to hit the purchased Cricket API server every 2s on my NODE JS server,is that a right way.I dont to the right way of doing this please help me.
Anyone out their working on same thing , i need help!

Answer (score 1):

If the Cricket API dosn' t support `Push Notification` (Ask the support) then `Pulling` is a necessary evil.

I would suggest creating a `cricket-api-adapter` server that will do the pulling form the `Cricket API`. This service can put each update to a PubSub/Queue for your other API servers to listen for updates.

Then you will be able to create a Gateway for your application clients to receive Push Notification from the system.